# scroll functionality not working when overflow hidden enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website consisting of three divs. two of those divs are nested inside the main div. The main div has a width of 100% and height of 100vh and overflow hidden. This will make the website unable to be scrolled and will hide the content underneath no matter what. Which is exactly what i am going for.

Now i want to bind an action to 'scrolling down' and 'scrolling up' but it seems, because scrolling is not possible on this webpage, the scrolling functionality has been turned off completely. How do I go about this? (I did find an unanswered thread about this but the person recommended me to not use overflow hidden, which i absolutely can't do.)

HTML

```
<div id ="main">
<div class="d1"> </div>
<div class="d2"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
width:100%;
height:100vh;
background-color:#999;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

JQuery

```
//Firefox
 $('#elem').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
 if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
     //scroll down
     alert("Down");
 }else {
     //scroll up
     alert("Up");
 }

 //prevent page fom scrolling
 return false;
 });

 //IE, Opera, Safar are not included to make this thread more clear
```

I hope you guys can help me,

Comment: Please provide a working jsFiddle. In the meantime, maybe this helps: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml